# I can't get datas from json file with angula.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have theses codes:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="pizzasApp">
    <head>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="configure.js"></script>
         <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pizza-list.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="pizza in pizzas">
    <a href="#/pizzas/{{pizza._id}}">{{pizza.name}}</a>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
(function(){    
    var pizzasApp = angular.module('pizzasApp',['ngRoute','app']);

    pizzasApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider.
        when('/pizzas',{
            templateUrl: 'pizza-list.html',
            controller: 'PizzasController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirecTo: '/pizzas'
        });
    }]);

})();
```

configure.js:

```
(function(){

     var app = angular.module('app',[]);

     app.controller('PizzasController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
         $http.get('http://162.250.78.47/api/pizzas').success(function(data){
              $scope.pizzas = data;
         });
     }]);

})();
```

The problem is that I can't get the datas from json file. I know that the problem isn't the json file because I can get the datas with other way but without angular-route. But I'm interested in that.

Comment: I am not sure the `(function(){` is necessary. Also, what's the output of data?

Comment: with (function(){ or without I have the same result. I can't get the data because of this there isn't output data. And the web debug tell me that everything is right.

Comment: Do you have any error in console? No CORS issues?

Comment: Only warning `http://localhost/api/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
http://localhost/api/angular-route.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
La codificación de caracteres del documento HTML no ha sido declarada. El documento se mostrará con texto "basura" en algunas configuraciones de navegador si el documento contiene caracteres externos al rango US-ASCII. La codificación de caracteres de la página debe ser declarada en el documento o en el protocolo de transferencia.` but isn't important for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: http://plnkr.co/edit/AsAPhINnDmBToTRFmgZf?p=preview

It looks like `.otherwise` is not doing its job when there is just a '/'. I hacked around it with:

```
$routeProvider.when('/pizzas',{
    templateUrl: 'pizza-list.html',
    controller: 'PizzasController'
}).when('/',{
  redirectTo: '/pizzas'
}).otherwise({
  redirecTo: '/pizzas'
});
```

Edit: I found the actual error, there were a typo in `redirectTo`. It was spelled `redirecTo`.